# In a friendly game of Texas Hold ’em, four people are dealt two cards each...

Tags: probability, poker

In a friendly game of Texas Hold ’em, four people are dealt two cards each. Considering there are 12
face cards, how many ways are there for everyone to get two face cards?

I need help on this problem. I don't know where to begin. I know the total amount of people is 4 and each get 2 cards to start so that could be $\frac{4!}{2!2!}$, then we have a total of 12 face cards distributed to 4 people and each need two. This is where I'm confused.

Comment: This is ambiguous.  Does the order of the hands matter?  That is to say, you have players $A,B,C,D$.  If $A$ and $B$ swap hands, is that a different arrangement or not?

Comment: No, if they switch it doesn't change the odds of drawing a face card.

Comment: That is not what I asked.  You are trying to count arrangements and to do so you have to specify which arrangements are distinct.  So, say $A$ has $K\spadesuit, J\spadesuit$ and $B$ has $Q\clubsuit, Q\heartsuit$ (and $C,D$ have whatever they have).  Then $A,B$ swap (while $C,D$ keep their hands).  So now $A$ has $Q\clubsuit, Q\heartsuit$ and $B$ has $K\spadesuit, J\spadesuit$. Is that the same arrangement or is that a different arrangement?

Comment: Regardless...if you assume that it matters who holds which hand, then: $A$ can be dealt any of $\binom {12}2$ hands, $B$ then can get $\binom {10}2$, $C$ can get $\binom 82$ and $D$ can get $\binom 62$ so the count (under that assumption) is the product of those $4$ numbers.  If you wanted the count up to permutation, you need only divide by $4!$

Comment: Oh okay, I see what you're saying now, thank you!

Comment: Ambiguity question.  Player A has two cards.  Does it matter if the order he receive them is switched?  If not, lulu is correct.